# How to calculate avg time visit per screen_class (firebase) in bigquery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I would like to calculate avg time as seen on the screenshot below using bigquery, but I'm not sure how to add the screen class in my query to be able to yield the same result, can you please help me?

My current query only sum up all values in engagement time msec

```
SELECT SUM(params.value.int_value) as total_engagement_time_msec,
event_date
FROM `datasetid.events_*`, UNNEST(event_params) as params 
WHERE event_name = 'user_engagement'
AND params.key = 'engagement_time_msec'
GROUP BY event_date
```

[image: avg time]

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking care of this case to provide you an update.

Your table seems to be grouped by screen class, indeed, that's why the avg aggregation is possible.

I'm not familiar with Firebase, but I found out the [BigQuery Export schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512) and [Event Parameter Details](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512) that your table in the image is probably using, especially the firebase_screen_class (Screen Class) and engagement_time_msec.

So, after checking your question to include Screen Class as a column, you might want to use two tables to group by firebase_screen_class, for example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH (
  SELECT params.key as screen_class, event_name
  FROM `datasetid.events_*`, UNNEST(event_params) as params 
  WHERE params.key = 'firebase_screen_class'
) as sc
SELECT event_date as eventDate, sc.screen_class as screenClass, AVG(engagement_time_msec) as totalEngagementTime
FROM `datasetid.events_*`, UNNEST(event_params) as params 
WHERE event_name = 'user_engagement'
AND params.key = 'engagement_time_msec'
INNER JOIN sc
ON sc.event_name==event_name
GROUP BY event_date, screenClass
```

Note: The query might need some adjustments